# Lenovo ThinkPad L380 USB boot missing

Tags: boot, laptop, thinkpad, usb-boot

I have lenovo thinkpad l380 laptop which I need to rebuild using USB but when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> I don't see USB as boot option.

I try same USB on different laptop and it does show and boot from it.

I already try following but still no lock

- OS Optimized Defaults = Disable
- Secure Boot = Disable
- UEFI/Legacy Boot = Legacy Only.
- Device Guard = Disable

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB which I was using is not compatible so i tried another usb and its all working.

I was try to installed Windows 10 21H2